# Ridge Regression: When should the intercept be included ? What is the purpose of the intercept term?

Tags: ridge-regression, intercept

I am trying to determine what is the purpose of including the intercept term in ridge regression.

In what situations should I include the intercept term ?

And in what situations should I not include the intercept term in ridge regression ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ridge regression is similar to multiple regression. The only difference is adding the L2 regularization to objective.

Therefore, this post answers your question well: 
[When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model)

In most cases, it is better to include intercept term, **and more importantly,  the regularization usually does not apply on the intercept.**.

The only reason we want to remove the intercept term is that we need $y=0$ when $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$.